# response.json() и JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript

вызов метода на ответе от сервере response.json() и JSON.parse() это не одно и тоже? в чем разница?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.parse()` нужен просто для десериализации json-строки, которая может храниться или создаваться в любой момент выполнения скрипта вне контекста обработки запросов.
Да, результат, который будет получен при выполнении обоих методов будет один и тот же, просто они используются для разных целей.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!